# Vectors of different lengths from a `for` cycle in R: merging in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following elementary issue in R.

I have a `for (k in 1:x){...}` cycle which produces numerical vectors whose length depends on `k`.
For each value of `k` I produce a single numerical vector.

I would like to collect them as rows of a data frame in R, if possible. In other words, I would like to introduce a data frame `data` s.t.

```
    for (k in 1:x) {
            data[k,] <- ...      
                     }
```

where the dots represent the command producing the vector with length depending on `k`.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, the length of the rows of a dataframe in R is constant, as it is a list of vectors of equal length. I have already tried to complete each row with a suitable number of zeroes to arrive at a constant length (in this case equal to `x`). I would like to work "dynamically", instead.

I do not think that this issue is equivalent to merge vectors of different lengths in a dataframe; due to the `if` cycle, only 1 vector is known at each step.

**Edit**

A very easy example of what I mean. For each `k`, I would like to write the vector whose components are `1,2,...,k` and store it as `k`th row of the dataframe `data`. In the above setting, I would write

```
 for (k in 1:x) {
                data[k,] <- seq(1,k,1)     
                         }
```

As the length of `seq(1,k,1)` depends on `k` the code does not work.

Comment: Could you please give a simple example of what you want to achieve? The wording of the question is a bit confusing, and I am not sure what you mean by the `if` cycle in : `I do not think that this issue is equivalent to merge vectors of different lengths in a dataframe; due to the "if" cycle, only 1 vector is known at each step`. Are you referring to some `ifelse()` statement? I don't see any in your code.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question accordingly! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396188/can-you-use-rbind-fill-without-having-it-fill-in-nas, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486693/rbind-2-vectors-of-different-lengths-by-their-names, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365885/combining-vectors-of-unequal-length-into-a-data-frame?rq=1 are related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using `ldply` from `plyr` here.

```
set.seed(123)
#k is the length of each result
k <- sample( 5 , 3 , repl = TRUE )
#[1] 2 4 3


# Make a list of vectors, each a sequence from 1:k
ll <- lapply( k , function(x) seq_len(x) )
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3

# take our list and rbind it into a data.frame, filling in missing values with NA
ldply( ll , rbind)
#  1 2  3  4
#1 1 2 NA NA
#2 1 2  3  4
#3 1 2  3 NA
```

Comment: If he wants the vectors to be the `rows` of the dataframe, I think we don't need to take the transpose of the final result. This `ldply( ll , rbind)` simply should do it.

Comment: By the way, very neat code.

Comment: I see: using lists one avoids the curse of dimensionality :-) . Very helpful, thanks!